# VBA UserForm - Code not working as expected when correlating

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

Let me preface this with saying fairly new to VBA.
But I've created a Userform that is taking in First Name, Last Name and Job Title.
Looking to correlate training to job title.
Code references named ranges (1)Merge_Title and (2)Merge_Training from the Merged_DF.

The error I'm encountering is seen in 'Results' pic below. Looking to simply have name, job, and all relevant training associated to that job (ref. Merge_DF pic).
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks again!

[Merge_DF Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyTGR.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxZ2n.png)

```
''' Submits userform into table
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lJob As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws_Merge As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    Set ws_Merge = Worksheets("MERGE_DF")

    'find first empty row in table
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    lJob = Me.CmboJob.ListIndex

    'verify data entered
    If Trim(Me.TextFirst.Value) = "" Then
        Me.TextFirst.SetFocus
        MsgBox "You Forgot the First Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.TextLast.Value) = "" Then
        Me.TextLast.SetFocus
        MsgBox "You Forgot the Last Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.CmboJob.Value) = "" Then
        Me.CmboJob.SetFocus
        MsgBox "You Forgot the Job Title"
        Exit Sub
    End If

   'loops and records data
    For Each c In ws_Merge.Range("Merge_Title")
        If c = Me.CmboJob.Value Then
            With ws
                .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.TextLast.Value
                .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextFirst.Value
                .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.CmboJob.Value
                For Each i In ws_Merge.Range("Merge_Training")
                    ws.Cells(lRow, 7).Value = i.Value
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                Next
                ' lRow = lRow + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next c

    Me.TextLast.Value = ""
    Me.TextFirst.Value = ""
    Me.CmboJob.Value = ""
    Me.CmboJob.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  May need a bit more backstory - is it erroring or not working fast enough?

Comment: If this code is working then it should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry - it's not working as intended, but I'll post it on Code Review if necessary.

Comment: Code isn't erroring - was initially wanting it to display all relevant training per job title. Idea was loop through all available job titles, then pull necessary training with nested for loops - but 'Results' pic is where I am atm

Comment: If its not working as expected, please edit your question with what is not working as expected and or what line you receive an error on please.  Not everyone can download pictures, so please edit so we can see the picture of results.

Comment: Let me know if more clarification is needed - the point was user could add individual and specify their job, and relevant training would populate.

Comment: Example: Marge Simpson - Chemist - would pull 3 training courses (Chemistry, Physics, Engineering). But if job were specified as a principle scientist - it would pull the 5 associated training courses(i.e. Chemistry, Physics, Biology, Engineering, Mathematics).

Comment: Is it safe to say you already have the list of Training Courses spelled out on the worksheet("Merge_Training")?  If so and the list is extremely long then I would use a `Dictionary` to store the items and a corresponding numeric key.  On a side note make sure you are using Option Explicit on all of your modules it will help debugging.  If its a short list then you could use the `Find` function and then concatenate the appropriate training courses.  Unfortunately, I am unable to see the results picture, so its tough to see where the training courses are actually being populated.